# php imap_open() is running slowly when connecting to localhost

Tags: php

system info: Running on CentOS release 6.2 (Final), PHP 5.3.3, Dovecot + postfix setup, Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

connection line:

```
$mbox = imap_open({'{localhost:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX','un','pw');
```

Changing the port and/or using the ip and domain name have no impact...

Consistently takes between 5.5 and 7 seconds to run the imap_open command...

any idea how I can get this to run faster?

Comment: Do you have firewall installed?

Comment: not unless the default linode Centos automatically added one...

Comment: @AsrafulHaque, image size??? this happens regardless of the mail message prior to opening any of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two steps to get you started. You want to isolate the cause - is it PHP or is it the local IMAP server. These steps use `telnet` and `strace`. You might need to install them first:

```
yum install telnet
yum install strace
```

**First:** [Test the connection locally using telnet](http://blog.andrewc.com/?p=15)

```
$ telnet localhost 143
...
  a LOGIN username password
```

Is there still a delay? If so - when: at the initial connection or after the `LOGIN` command? If there is a delay, the problem is related to IMAP on your server and not PHP.

**Second:** If connecting through telnet is quick, make a minimal PHP-script and debug it using `strace`

```
<?php
   // save this as imap_test.php
   $mbox = imap_open({'{localhost:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX','un','pw');
?>

$ strace -t -s 200 php ./imap_test.php
```

To save the output from strace to a file `strace.log`:

```
$ strace -t -s 200 php ./imap_test.php 2>&1 > strace.log

strace writes all its output to stderr.
2>&1 means to combine stderr with stdout, then > to write to the logfile.
If you want to see the output AND write it to a file, use tee:

$ strace -t -s 200 php ./imap_test.php 2>&1 | tee strace.log
```

You will get lots of output. Try to see if and where it hangs, waiting for something. It is often useful to quickly press ENTER several times when you see it hanging - that way it's easier to locate by scrolling back in the output after the command has finished.

With a little patience (and luck) you should be able to detect where PHP is waiting, and for what.

**Edit:** (or *what happened next*)

One issue was with SSL/TLS which caused delays. Adding the `/notls` option solved it:

```
// This should be ok for internal connections to localhost, but you really 
// dont want to disable TLS on an open network
$mbox = imap_open('{localhost:143/imap/notls}INBOX','un','pw');
```

Disabling TLS causes PHP warnings. [Here is a discussion about handling them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766203/suppress-bogus-php-imap-open-notice-insecure-server-advertised-auth-plain)

One *further* issue was authentication methods. Basically php's imap_open will try all protocols. People complained for years and it was finally fixed by adding a new parameter in php 5.3:[3]

```
$mbox = imap_open('{localhost:143/imap/notls}INBOX','un','pw',NULL,1,array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => array('GSSAPI','NTLM)));
```

Long story short: from 6 seconds to maybe 6 miliseconds.

[3] https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33500

Comment: this is awesomeness itself. How can I pipe strace to a file? It's taking 6 seconds just with the side.

Comment: @virmaior Edit: I've added it to the answer

Comment: it's not actually piping with 2>&1 > strace.log ... still just seeing it on the console (I'm on Centos btw)

Comment: If your shell is `bash`, `2>&1` should definitely work. Could you paste the exact command you are running? Most importantly - are you getting any clues about what's causing the delay? What lines are displayed just before the delay? You can always abort with `Ctrl-c` when it's stopping at the delay, to ignore the rest of the output from strace.

Comment: This line seems to take 4 seconds: 

01:39:17 select(4, [3], NULL, [3], {60, 0}) = 1 (in [3], left {55, 996282})

might the problem be that the e-mails are in the mbox format?

similar 4 second delay for an account that has less than 100 messages in it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44380/discussion-between-grebneke-and-virmaior)